# Float: left; Alternative for making divs in one line?

Tags: html, css

So currently I'm working on a portfolio and I can't use Bootstrap because it's not compatible with the website (it screws everything up, I could just make some tweaks but that's not the point) so I'm trying to make 3 divs on the same line **without** using `float: left;` how should I do this without bootstrap or tables?

```
        <div id="Portfolio">
            <div class="portfolioWrapper">

                <a class="portfolioLink" href="#">
                <div class="portfolioProject">
                    <h4>Sample Project</h4>
                </div>
                </a>

                <a class="portfolioLink" href="#">
                <div class="portfolioProject">
                    <h4>Sample Project</h4>
                </div>
                </a>

                <a class="portfolioLink" href="#">
                <div class="portfolioProject">
                    <h4>Sample Project</h4>
                </div>
                </a>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `display: table` & `table-cell` or `flex` or `inline-block`. many choices avalaible, what have you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the display property to flex will allow the items to sit in one line as long as the are not too wide.

```css
.portfolioWrapper {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-around; 
}
```

```html
        <div id="Portfolio">
            <div class="portfolioWrapper">

                <a class="portfolioLink" href="#">
                <div class="portfolioProject">
                    <h4>Sample Project</h4>
                </div>
                </a>

                <a class="portfolioLink" href="#">
                <div class="portfolioProject">
                    <h4>Sample Project</h4>
                </div>
                </a>

                <a class="portfolioLink" href="#">
                <div class="portfolioProject">
                    <h4>Sample Project</h4>
                </div>
                </a>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Well, first you need to move your anchors inside the `div` containers:</strike>

<strike>`<div class="portfolioProject">`</strike>

<strike>`<a class="portfolioLink" href="#"><h4>Sample Project</h4></a>`</strike>

<strike>`</div>`</strike>

You can use CSS selectors to set `display: inline-block` on the child anchors to get them to display next to each other, like so:

`div > a { display: inline-block;}`

Edit: @GCyrillus pointed out that you don't need to put the anchors back inside the divs if the document type is HTML5.  You can fix this with the following CSS:

```
 div > a {
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

[Updated JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/poy5Ldqm/1/)

Comment: no need to move anchor  inside divs, if the doctype used is html 5, it is valid and `<a>` can take any display value :)

Comment: Thanks @GCyrillus, I didn't know that.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting .portfolioWrapper to position relative and then set all .portfolioLink to display: inline-block and set a width of 33% depending on the length of your outer container. You shouldn't need to use a float if you use inline-block.

```css
.portfolioWrapper {
    position: relative;
  }

.portfolioLink { 
   display:inline-block;
   width: 33%;  
  }
```